# Element goes right even with float left

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and for the life of me I cannot figure out what the problem with my code is. I want to have one long element with a short one underneath it on the left. Then i want to have two short elements side by side to the long one.

so to draw you a very simple map this is what i'm after:
Diagram of what i'm after

[image]

Even though I set the larger element and a smaller element to float left, still three go to the right. Like I said i'm new to this so it's probably something silly, but if anyone could help that'd be great

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/es09vLc0/

**HTML**

```css
html {
  background-color:black;
}
.blogPostsContainer {
  width:100%;
  border:solid;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.blogPost {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:black;
  width:49%;
  border:solid;
  border-color:#FFF010;
  border-radius:1px;
  color:white;
  margin-top:10px;
  height:240px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.blogPost h3 {
  color:white;
}
.blogPost h1 {    
  text-align:center;
  border-color:dodgerblue;
  border:solid;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
}
.blogPost img {
  width:95%;
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="BlogPostsContainer">
  <div class="blogPost"  style="height:700px; float:left">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-1.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:right">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-2.jpg" />
    <h1>DESCRIPT</h1>
    <h3>THIS IS DESCRIPTIONNNN
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:left">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-3.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:right">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-3.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
      This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the box with the `float: left` to the end and added a div named "clear" with css `clear: both`.

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
}
.blogPostsContainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.blogPost {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 49%;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #FFF010;
  border-radius: 1px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blogPost h3 {
  color: white;
}
.blogPost h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  border: solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.blogPost img {
  width: 95%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="BlogPostsContainer">
  <div class="blogPost" style="height:700px; float:left">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-1.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
            </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:right">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-2.jpg" />
    <h1>DESCRIPT</h1>
    <h3>THIS IS DESCRIPTIONNNN
            </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:right">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-3.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
            </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="blogPost" style="float:left">
    <img src="home_page/images/test/hqdefault-3.jpg" />
    <h1>This is the Title section</h1>
    <h3>This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
                This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.This is the description.
            </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, however i'm still confused as to why the element goes right, even though i floated it left. can you shed any light on this?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of CSS floats first. You'll easily find 10 million tutorials on this. Your current assumptions about how float works are completely off.

Comment: @HansDonkersloot `float: left;` will try to fit the element towards the left if there's enough space for it. If there's none, that's when you'll get the desired effect of having it at the bottom. With your current layout there's enough room for it so it got placed on the side, not bottom.

Comment: Just clear the last float, no need to insert an empty element.

Comment: I just added the empty element to get more overview.